How to Filter Rows of a Table Using a List of Primary Keys in Ibis Framework
Problem: I need to filter rows per ID. But I'd like to make it more general such that client user can provide more than 1 ID. I decided to write my code this way using the concept of %in% on SQL language. e.g. In SQL, we filter rows using WHERE ID == 1 and we use ID %in% [1,2,3] to filter using more.

Solution: A colleague of mine found this in the Ibis Chatrooms.
filtered = t.filter(t.two > 0, t.one.isin(["A", "B"]))
